# word2vecに関するエラー

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, word2vec

[【Python】Word2Vecで単語の分散表現を体感する](https://zenn.dev/robes/articles/61847e68587b98)

を参考にし、word2vecをGoogle Colabratoryで動かそうと試みたのですが、

```
!pip install gensim
!pip install SudachiPy==0.5.4 ginza==4.0.6 ja-ginza==4.0.0 sklearn pandas
```

の部分でエラーが起きてしまいます。
下はこの部分の実行結果です。原因を調べて、pipやその他のアップグレード等試しましたが、何度やってもこうなってしまいます。
何が原因なんでしょうか？

```
Requirement already satisfied: gensim in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim) (1.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open>=1.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim) (6.4.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Collecting SudachiPy==0.5.4
  Using cached SudachiPy-0.5.4.tar.gz (86 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting ginza==4.0.6
  Using cached ginza-4.0.6.tar.gz (20 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting ja-ginza==4.0.0
  Using cached ja_ginza-4.0.0.tar.gz (51.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post9.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: こちら [sklearn 0.0.post9 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) の最初の記述やこちらの記事 [Difference between scikit-learn and sklearn (now deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38733220/9014308) に sklearn は廃止されたので scikit-learn に変えてくださいとあります。それで駄目なら時期的 [Release history](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/#history) に参照記事が使っていたであろう 0.0 の版数を指定してインストールするとか、pip だけではなく setuptools も更新するとか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: `!pip install ginza ja-ginza` で ginza-5.1.3 がインストールされます。普通に動いてそう。また `!pip install gensim`なくても `from gensim.models import word2vec` は可能。
なぜ (何の目的で) `ginza==4.0.6` などのようにバージョン指定してますか？

Comment: @oriri さん、おそらく参照記事に書いてある通りに1字1句変えずに作業したのだと思われます。実際には記事の作者の作業が何時行われたか不明ですが、記事自身は1年2ヵ月前なのでそれほど古くは無いと考えられたのでは？

Comment: @kunif  さん, そうであればそれについて(最新使うほうがよいと)回答できるかもしれないし, そうでなければ何に拘ってるのか判明するかもしれません(そしてそれについて何か示せるかもしれない)。いずれにしても「なぜそれを選択したのか」の理由は質問に記されていたほうがよいと思うですよ